# how to add keys from an existing dictionary to a new dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, del

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
pris = {'äpplen': [12,13,15,16,17], 'bananer': [14,17,18,19], 'citroner': [20,13,14,15,16], 'hallon': [23,34,45,46,57], 'kokos': [12,45,67,89]}
```

an another:

```
t={'äpplen', 'bananer', 'hallon'}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a new dictionary with only the elements in t.

```
New_dictionary= {'äpplen': [12,13,15,16,17], 'bananer': [14,17,18,19], 'hallon': [23,34,45,46,57]}
```

So far, I've done this:
I tried to remove the not desired keys in dictionary pris, but I get all the elements that I don't want. I tried with append, etc, but it doesn't work.

```
for e in t: 
    if e is not pris:
        del pris[e]
print(pris)
```

```
>>> {'citroner': [20, 13, 14, 15, 16], 'kokos': [12, 45, 67, 89]}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `if is not` is a syntax error…!?

Comment: I forgot the e while writing the question.

Comment: `t={'äpplen', 'bananer', 'hallon'}` is not a dictionary. It is a set.

Comment: the ```t``` variable should contain all the elements that you want to delete not the elements that you want to keep you can find the difference by using ```t = set(pris.keys()).difference(t)``` and looping through the new set

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
new_d = dict()
for key in t:
    if key in pris:
        new_d[key] = pris[key]
```

here is how in 1 line

```
new_d = {key:pris[key] for key in t if key in pris}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_dict = {}
for e in t:
   if e in pris.keys():
      new_dict[e] = pris[e]
```

Answer (score -1):

New_dictionary={k:pris[k] for k in t}